# Gradient of UIButton is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, gradient

I’m trying to put a gradient on a button, but it is not showing up. All the other button parts are working and displaying perfectly!

**Function that creates the button**

```
private func createButtonMenu(buttonTitle: String, buttonIcon: UIImage, colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) -> UIButton{

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
        button.contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let icon = UIImageView(image: buttonIcon)
        icon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.addSubview(icon)

        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true


        icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        icon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        //button.backgroundColor = .red
        icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

        return button
    }
```

**Function that inserts the button in view**

```
private func configuringButtons(){
        //Creating buttons
        let userButtonMenu: UIButton = createButtonMenu(buttonTitle: "009", buttonIcon:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "woman"), colorOne: .red, colorTwo: .blue)
        view.addSubview(userButtonMenu)
}
```

Comment: Didnt work Chris, the backgroundColor works just as expected, but the gradient doesnt

Comment: let try `button.addSubview(icon)` to `button.imageView = icon`

Comment: button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
dont you think it shouls not be on 0 but on top i mean on totallayers.count

Answer (score 0):

Colours in a gradient layer must be of type `CGColor`, not `UIColor`.

```
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
```

Comment: @VinniciusPereira Are you getting any errors or is it just not working?